# Pointer or reference variables

Tags: powershell

I want to use indirect reference variable. 
I am setting this at Command Prompt

```batch
SET RiskScheduler=true
```

My code is like this

```bsh
Write-Host "$Env:RiskScheduler"  # prints true
```

I want to achieve the same should be printed with code like this

```bsh
$name='RiskScheduler'  
Write-host $name                # prints RiskScheduler
Write-Host $Env:$name           # gives error
```

The error I am getting is

```
Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is invalid.
Change the value of the "path" argument and run the operation again.
At D:\tmp\buildtools\udclient.6.2\ud_clean.PS1:37 char:17
+ Write-Host $Env: <<<< `$name`
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument
```

I am looking for something that shall first evaluate `$name` and then evaluate `$Env:(value of $name)`.

Can someone please suggest, what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can do this with:

```
$x = 'RiskScheduler'
Write-Host (Get-Item env:$x).Value
```

Which will output `true` in your case

If you have a list of variable names:

```
$varNames = @('COMPUTERNAME', 'SESSIONNAME', 'RiskScheduler')

ForEach($varName in $varNames) {
    Write-Host (Get-Item env:$varName).Value
}
```

Which will output:

```
MyPcName
Console
true
```

You can find more information about this by entering `Get-Help about_environment_variables` into PowerShell:

> Get-Item -Path Env:* | Get-Member
>
> Displaying Environment Variables
>      You can use the cmdlets that contain the Item noun (the Item cmdlets) to 
>      display and change the values of environment variables. Because 
>      environment variables do not have child items, the output of Get-Item
>      and Get-ChildItem is the same.
>
> When you refer to an environment variable, type the Env: drive name 
>     followed by the name of the variable. For example, to display the value 
>     of the COMPUTERNAME environment variable, type:
>
> Get-Childitem Env:Computername

---

**Option 2**

Another option would be to use this function:

```
function Get-EnvVar($Name) {
    $allVars = dir env:

    foreach ($var in $allVars) {
        If ($var.Name -eq $Name) {
            return $var
        }
    }
}
```

The function iterates around all available environment variables and returns the one you are after (in this case, `$Env:COMPUTERNAME`).

You can then call

`Write-Host $myvar.Value`

to display the value of `COMPUTERNAME`

If you have an array of variable names you want the value of:

```
$varNames = @('COMPUTERNAME', 'SESSIONNAME', 'RiskScheduler')

ForEach($varName in $varNames) {
    $var = Get-EnvVar -Name $varName
    Write-Host $var.Value
}
```

Which outputs (for me) :

```
MyPcName
Console
true
```

Comment: actually in my case the "name" is variable, there are lot of such values, I want to put those in array and read one by one, do not want to write repeated code. can you give some suggestions.

Comment: You can achieve that with my solution by simple creating an array of your variable names and then iterating around each one, calling `Get-EnvVar` to retrieve the value

Comment: @AmarKumbhar I found the actual solution and added it to the top of my answer, hope that helps